# Cannot get in touch with Stack Overflow Ads

Tags: support, advertising

Ten days ago I have submitted my request to be contacted using this form:
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise

When I click "*Request a call*" I get:

> One of our dedicated experts will be reaching out to you soon.

In any case I haven't received any call or email yet. I am located in Italy.

Is that normal? How long should I wait?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367645/spam-flag-declined-on-link-from-founder-cto-dozens-of-similar-posts) might require your attention.

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ Yes, thanks, I have been contacted privately by moderators.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for delay - I'm looking into why you haven't been contacted. Someone will reach out shortly!

Comment: It is not  [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514), right?   .... ;)

Comment: :) Nope...it was 5 minutes.