# Spam flag declined on link from Founder & CTO, dozens of similar posts

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

Yesterday, I ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501619/how-can-i-do-push-notifications-in-an-html5-web-application/36130498#36130498) answer. To me, it seemed a little odd to "casually" drop the name of a service, so I did a little digging. [The user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51387/collimarco) who posted the answer is, per his own profile, the **Founder & CTO at Pushpad**. Naturally, this is spam, as the help center [clearly states](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

> you must disclose your affiliation in your answers

The flag was promptly declined, given the reason of no evidence. This struck me as odd, so I did some more digging, as I suspected it wasn't a one-off thing.

Here's what I found, in addition to dozens more links to blog posts from his company *without disclosure* in most cases. I have left out responses that were relevant to the question, though I did go through this relatively quickly, so I may have wrongly missed or included some.

[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501619/how-can-i-do-push-notifications-in-an-html5-web-application/36130498#36130498)
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094281/can-we-use-aws-sns-to-send-web-push-notification/50097462#50097462)
[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514571/firebase-push-notifications-on-safari/48517558#48517558)
[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335947/can-i-send-a-web-notification-on-a-specific-time/47356293#47356293)
[[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291391/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-web-application-and-browser/47295594#47295594)
[[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220396/web-push-notifications-on-chrome-for-android-do-i-need-a-third-party-service-li/44225718#44225718)
[[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165517/are-multiple-gcm-sender-ids-mandatory-for-multiple-site-web-push/43166741#43166741)
[[8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812706/web-notifications-subscribers-data-endpoint-send-notifications/42816741#42816741)
[[9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626478/mozillas-web-apinotification-vs-clevertap-web-push/40628019#40628019)
[[10]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511734/identifying-users-in-rails-web-push-notifications/40531188#40531188)
[[11]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298292/does-my-web-application-require-ssl-for-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-web-to-work/40304130#40304130)
[[12]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972694/web-push-on-mozilla-with-group-ids/39974009#39974009)
[[13]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800518/what-actually-happens-when-we-call-serviceworkerregistration-pushmanager-subscri/39819166#39819166)
[[14]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155445/real-time-notification-for-angular-2-web-app-with-asp-net-web-api-back-end/37164315#37164315)
[[15]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078933/any-way-to-send-push-style-web-notifications-to-mobile-devices/37085846#37085846)
[[16]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428360/push-notification-services-in-web-application-php/36338961#36338961)
[[17]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313563/push-notifications-on-php-based-website/36224231#36224231)
[[18]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239704/sending-push-notifications-in-non-native-app-web-app/36130356#36130356)
[[19]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381681/mobile-website-push-notifications-after-session-over/36130048#36130048)
[[20]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app/36129840#36129840)
[[21]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156099/push-notification-facility-for-mobile-web-app/36129481#36129481)
[[22]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser/36129303#36129303)
[[23]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542287/are-push-notifications-possible-in-html5-without-fully-https-site/34976618#34976618)
[24]
[[25]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404427/web-push-api-send-notifications-to-multiple-recipients/49405704#49405704)

[1] is the original answer I had a declined spam flag on, and [25] I feel is questionable. The other 23 seem to be textbook cases of blatant self-promotion without *any* disclosure.

I raised this issue to the user in the original answer I flagged, and he seems to think he is doing enough by having it on his profile.

> The fact that I am the founder is clearly described in my StackOverflow profile... and it is also described in the answer that I have linked. In any case it is a relevant resource strictly related to the question: I think that most people will consider it useful.

I responded that usefulness is irrelevant, and that you must disclose the affiliation in the answer itself, per the help center referenced above.

Am I being overly pedantic, or is this not a blatant case of spam? I know if it were up to me, this account would be nuked, having two dozen self-promotion answers, plus dozens more blog links.

NB: I have only spam flagged [1]. The other 24 I have not touched, pending input. If the community agrees, I won't hesitate to spam flag the remaining.

*Edit: [24] has been removed as there was a disclosure.*

Comment: Moderators sometimes tend to make snap decisions on flags, because they get thousands of flags per day that they need to handle. As such, if it isn't entirely clear as to why a post is spam/R/A/NAA/etc., I always use a custom flag. In the case of spam and R/A, a single flag from a moderator is enough to spam-delete.

Comment: My adblocker even refuses to let me open that domain.

Comment: @yivi Hm, I didn't even try that. uBlock does the same for me.

Comment: I have contacted the user privately.  Please refrain from flagging these for now.

Comment: Link 24: "If you are looking for a drop in solution I would suggest Pushpad, which is a service I have built." for that one at least there's disclosure

Comment: I clearly added a disclaimer when referencing a product and still got flagged and -100.  i think it depends on the mood of the moderator,.

Comment: whatever, it still wasn't fair in my opinion i followed the rules and my answers were relevant to the question...AND used a disclaimer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Like I said, I quickly went through. I'll remove that link in a minute.

Comment: @JerylCook happy to engage you in chat as that's another issue... but I see nothing on your account that, that even happened

Comment: related: [What is the policy regarding sparse self-promotion in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361313/839601)

Comment: @JonClements feel free to review https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4854/115 to see my understanding of Jeryl's situation at GIS.

Comment: @collimarco Doing the courtesy of  notifying the [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51387/collimarco).

Comment: Looks like most (if not all) have been edited to include affiliation.

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ you can't ping a user on a post that the user wasn't involved on.  If you want to point them to a specific meta post about their contributions, you either need to ping them via a comment on one of those posts or find them in chat.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, that is spam, but because it's not going to be clear to a moderator reviewing the flag merely by looking at the post (you know it's spam due to lots of outside information you have about it), merely a spam flag alone isn't appropriate; you should be using a custom moderator flag, explaining what you found in your research, and why that makes the post spam.

Comment: Would a moderator not open up the profile? It literally doesn't take anything more than that to realize it's spam.

Comment: @jhpratt No, they're not going to look at the profile of every post that's flagged in the off chance that there might be incriminating evidence there.  If you've found something on someone's profile that indicates that a post is in fact spam (or otherwise problematic) then *you need to be explicit about that*, rather than demanding that the mod redo all of the research that you've already done.

Comment: @jhpratt Read my comment. Moderators get *thousands* of flags a day that they need to handle quickly. As such, they can sometimes make snap decisions on flags. For instance, I once had a flag declined for not using normal close votes on a question I had flagged for closure because it had a bounty on it.

Comment: @Servy Do mods see comments on flagged posts? I saw this answer as well realized it was spam because of  jhpratt's comment.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic They can, but if the comment is buried down, they're less likely to actually look. If it's up top their eyes might catch it.

Comment: @gparyani FWIW: I've had good results using custom moderator flags on bountied off-topic posts. Make sure to mention the presence of the bounty in your flag comments.

Comment: @pnuts Lots of people flag questions for closure either because they don't have close vote privileges, they have already voted to close and want the question closed more quickly, etc.  That happens way more often than close worthy questions being bountied.  Rather than assuming the mod is going to notice things that aren't very apparent, you should be explicit about that information.

Comment: @pnuts I don't see how that relates to my comment.  That duplicates are often apparent doesn't mean the mod realizes you're flagging the post because it has a bounty and only a mod can remove it, rather than because you don't have CV privileges or because your one vote didn't close the question as quickly as you like (the far more common reasons people flag a question asking for it to be closed, both of which are invalid flags).  If you're in an exceptional situation *explain that situation* rather than hoping the mod realizes it.  If you don't, you're rolling the dice on whether they notice.

Comment: Apart from what Servy has already told, there is no need to flag each and every post of the user. One custom moderator flag pointing out the issue at hand is enough.

Answer (score 13):

Since this proves that evidence needs to accompany spam flags, [created a feature request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310041/allow-to-add-incriminating-evidence-to-a-spam-flag).

<sub>(I wonder if this will be flagged as spam... I do disclose affiliation! :-) )</sub>

UPDATE: the declination reasoning for the previous such FR was found obsolete, challenged and updated, and feedback, especially from the SO mods, is needed to assess the validity of some of the points.
Also suggested an alternative solution.

UPDATE2: I'm okay with [@JonEricson's suggestion to handle obvious and non-obvious spam differently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/263693/3). [The note for the spam flag will need to be updated so that users know this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251565/add-optional-box-for-spam-flags-letting-you-say-why-you-think-its-spam/310066#comment1012769_263693).

Currently, we both seem to be waiting for any community feedback on this. It's up to you to provide it to move things further.

Comment: I see your suggestion got pretty much shutdown on MSE, but I think you are onto something. Either it should be made clear that the spam flag exists for "not an answer just an ad" spam and the mod flag should be used in subtle situations, or an optional explanation field should be added to the spam flag to handle those subtle situation.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic the Q&A they closed it as a duplicate of basically argues that such cases are too rare to warrant a streamlined mechanism. But no-one has access to the figures to (dis)prove anything with them. All I can see we can do is make ever more commotion (e.g. reopen the question) and make whatever more valid points weren't prominently made yet.

Comment: FYI: If you have reporting privileges for SmokeDetector, you can supply a reason for reporting using the command `!!/report [link1] [link2]... "reason in quotes"`.

Comment: Basically, you're linking to a **status-declined** post. So your answer is not helpful.

Comment: This doesn't prove that evidence needs to accompany spam flags.  It shows that *in rare instances* there are a certain type of spam posts, that make up a small minority of spam posts, that require additional evidence, and *in those rare cases* you need to use a custom flag, which is a perfectly acceptable tool to handle those exceptional situations (and not requiring additional site features to support).  For all of the non-rare cases where that isn't needed, spam flags work great.

Comment: @gparyani Does SmokeDetector's action register as spam flags? If yes, the figures at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251565/add-optional-box-for-spam-flags-letting-you-say-why-you-think-its-spam/263693#263693 are skewed and can't be trusted!

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev If you report something to SmokeDetector, it raises it for the attention of participants, who then flag it as spam.

Comment: @gparyani So, indeed, [a large portion of spam flags comes from a source other than SE users, and the observed percentage doesn't reflect UX!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251565/add-optional-box-for-spam-flags-letting-you-say-why-you-think-its-spam/310066#310066)