# Why is this question off topic and how can I improve it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed, flag-history

Can I somewhere find the discussion containing the reasons why this question is off topic?

I found it very useful, as well as the answers and I would improve it if I knew how.

The question: [Web Push notifications on Chrome for Android: Do I need a third party service like GCM or SNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220396/web-push-notifications-on-chrome-for-android-do-i-need-a-third-party-service-li)

Comment: From the close reason: *"We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations."*

Comment: If you like the post, then perhaps you should not post it on meta.. unless you plan to gain another 9K reputation points. Don't forget to keep a direct link to the post ;)

Comment: It appears as though it was single-handedly closed as off topic, by a user that doesn't exist anymore (aka this was a past moderator action?)

Comment: I don't have the time to dig in right now, so not writing an answer at the moment, but this seems to be asking whether it's _possible_ to do without a third-party service, not to _recommend_ one.  I think this could potentially be on-topic.

Comment: I'm thinking the same, but, given it may have been a mod action, and it's a self answer... i wonder if there's more to it we can't see. The self answer appears to be a copy paste from elsewhere.

Comment: Seems to be open now.

Comment: Well, it appears the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44225718) on that question was part of a [spam/ lack-of-disclosure kerfuffle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367645); I'd hazard a guess that this was why there was mod activity on the question, rather than there being anything exceptionally wrong with it. That mod probably just saw the question, thought it was off-topic, and closed it in passing.

Answer (score 17):

The question appears to be on-topic to me. It is a bit high-level, which may make it feel like it leans towards being general computing, but it's clearly asking what's necessary in order to accomplish a programming task, rather than a task which would be general computing. I've reopened it. While it was originally closed by a moderator, there's nothing other than the publicly available information which indicates why that moderator closed it.